# Search data only day value of date

Tags: c#, mysql, date

Is it possible to search a data by day or month value of a date type value in mysql and c#.net.please can any one help me?

Answer (score 3):

You can use DAY and MONTH functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE DAY(date_column) = 1
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
WHERE MONTH(date_column) = 1
```

have a look at [MySQL date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html).